# Why does ffmpeg yuv420p conversion affect pixels beyond 2x2 blocks?

Tags: ffmpeg

Why does the YUV420 conversion in `ffmpeg` seem to operate beyond the 2x2 pixel blocks?

```
# Create a test image.
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=1:size=160x120:rate=1 -y original.png

# Create a new image after converting to YUV420 and back to RGB.
ffmpeg -i original.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo - | \
  ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 160x120 -i - -pix_fmt rgb24 -y yuv420.png

# Compare upscaled versions of the two images.
convert original.png -interpolate Nearest -filter point -resize 800% original.scaled.png
convert yuv420.png -interpolate Nearest -filter point -resize 800% yuv420.scaled.png
display original.scaled.png yuv420.scaled.png  # press spacebar to advance
```

Note how pixels are modified even at a distance of 2 pixels from the horizontal bar
in the lower part of the image.

See the result:
[image]

and closeup:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to introduce `-sws_flags` to specify non-default filtering options for the chroma subsampling:

```
ffmpeg -i original.png -sws_flags 'area+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int' \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo - \
| ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 160x120 -i - \
  -sws_flags 'neighbor+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int' -pix_fmt rgb24 -y yuv420.png
```

(By default, the chroma resampling uses a bicubic filter, does not provide accurate rounding, and uses some poor interpolation function.)

See also [Why is ffmpeg's conversion to YUV420 so poor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64729698/why-is-ffmpegs-conversion-to-yuv420-so-poor) where it is shown that the default options result in worse quality (PSNR) in a roundtrip conversion RGB -> YUV420 -> RGB.