# Why is ffmpeg's conversion to YUV420 so poor?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been using `ffmpeg` and other compression tools to compare rate-distortion curves for YUV420-resampled video.
In these comparisons, results from `ffmpeg` are consistently worse, with PSNR values that are 0.5-1.0 dB lower.

I tracked the problem to `ffmpeg`'s conversion between RGB and YUV420.
To simplify, let us assume "lossless compression" and therefore consider only RGB -> YUV420 -> RGB.
Also, we operate on a single PNG image frame.

```
# Use some default options.
ffmpeg="ffmpeg -nostdin -hide_banner -v error"

# Obtain a source image.
wget -nv -O original.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J1qY.png
size="256x256"

# Compare it with itself to verify that we get an infinite average PSNR.
$ffmpeg -v info -i original.png -i original.png -lavfi psnr -f null - |& grep PSNR
# average:inf

# Convert the image to YUV420, and convert back to RGB.
$ffmpeg -i original.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -y temp1.yuv420
$ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s $size -pix_fmt yuv420p -i temp1.yuv420 -y result1.png

# Compare it with the original image to measure the PSNR (in dB).
$ffmpeg -v info -i result1.png -i original.png -lavfi psnr -f null - |& grep PSNR
# average:36.894551
```

Now, as an alternative, we perform the RGB <-> YUV420 chroma resampling manually:

```
yuv444_to_yuv420="extractplanes=y+u+v[y][u][v];\
  [u]scale=w=iw/2:h=ih/2:flags=area[u];\
  [v]scale=w=iw/2:h=ih/2:flags=area[v];\
  [y][u][v]mergeplanes=0x001020:yuv420p"
yuv420_to_rgb="extractplanes=y+u+v[y][u][v];\
  [u]scale=w=iw*2:h=ih*2:flags=neighbor[u];\
  [v]scale=w=iw*2:h=ih*2:flags=neighbor[v];\
  [y][u][v]mergeplanes=0x001020:yuv444p,format=rgb24"

$ffmpeg -i original.png -pix_fmt yuv444p -f rawvideo - | \
  $ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv444p -s $size -i - \
    -lavfi "$yuv444_to_yuv420" -f rawvideo -y temp2.yuv420
$ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s $size -i temp2.yuv420 \
  -lavfi "$yuv420_to_rgb" -y result2.png

# Measure PSNR by comparing with the original image.
$ffmpeg -v info -i result2.png -i original.png -lavfi psnr -f null - |& grep PSNR
# average:37.536444
# This is an improvement of 0.64 dB!
```

This brings up two questions:

1. Why doesn't `ffmpeg` implement a better conversion to/from `yuv420p` by default?
2. Is there any simpler way to obtain or express this improved conversion?

Comment: RGB 8 bit -> YUV420 -> RGB 8 bit is not lossless at all, RGB 8 bit -> YUV420 10 bits -> RGB 8 bit would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimentation, I did manage to find two workarounds:

(1) The argument `-sws_flags` sets the parameters of all implicitly introduced `swscale` filters in the filter graph.
It appears that these filters are also responsible for the YUV420 conversion.
With carefully chosen filter flags, it works:

```
$ffmpeg -i original.png -sws_flags 'area+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int' \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -y temp1.yuv420

$ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s $size -pix_fmt yuv420p -i temp1.yuv420 \
  -sws_flags 'neighbor+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int' -y result1.png

$ffmpeg -v info -i result1.png -i original.png -lavfi psnr -f null - |& grep PSNR
# average:37.567842
```

(2) It is also possible to specify the filtering options as parameters of a `scale` filter (with default 100% scale) which performs `rgb24->yuv420p` or `yuv420p->rgb24` format conversion depending on the input format requested by the next graph node:

```
$ffmpeg -v info -i original.png \
  -lavfi 'scale=flags=area+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int,format=yuv420p' \
  -f rawvideo -y temp1.yuv420

$ffmpeg -v info -f rawvideo -s $size -pix_fmt yuv420p -i temp1.yuv420 \
  -lavfi 'scale=flags=neighbor+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int' -y result1.png

$ffmpeg -v info -i result1.png -i original.png -lavfi psnr -f null - |& grep PSNR
# average:37.567842
```

It's unfortunate that this behavior is not the default, but at least there is a semi-convenient way to access it.

Comment: Is there a way to apply either of these workarounds when trying to output an h264 video with yuv420p pixel format from a batch of png files? An example command: ffmpeg -y -framerate 30 -i '%03d.png' -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -vf format=yuv420p -crf 1 output.mp4